# How to use default constructor in codeIgniter4?

Tags: codeigniter-4, php-7.4

I want to use controller to load directly some models by using default constructor, but CodeIgniter4 was removed **__construct** method from CodeIgniter4 framework and I got error message ***Cannot call constructor***. please see code below:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    //Do magic task here
}
```

Instead of CI3 is working by using above code, Can anyone suggest me in CI4?

Thank You for your tips or comments!

Best Regards!

Comment: You have use this constructor method and within where Do magic task is written, you have to create instance of your model.

Answer (score 1):

CI4 default controller namespaced `CodeIgniter\Controller` doesn't have a class constructor. So if you're extending directly from it, `parent::__construct()` can't be called.

If you really need a constructor for every one of your controller you should modify App\Controllers\BaseController and making your others controllers extending it with the code you provided.

Also if your goal is to execute some code before or after your controller is called you should check out Filters in CI4. They are perfectly designed for this need : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html

Comment: It's still not work, even i trying to extending to BaseController, I've been review in BaseController class in Controllers folder it's deosn't have __construct method.

Comment: Yes so add one `__construct` method without `parent::__construct()` into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor in CI4 to load models

Add the code in your Controller class and it should work.

```
    protected $userModel;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userModel = new UserModel();//Create a instance of the model
        helper('form', 'url');
    }
```